# Export from solr: Unknown query parser 'xport'

Tags: java, solr, solr4

I tried following [this tutorial](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Exporting+Result+Sets) to export solr result set, but upon accessing the export url `http://localhost:8983/solr/emails/export?q=*%3A*&sort=date+desc&fl=id` I received the following error:

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
  <int name="status">400</int>
  <int name="QTime">17</int>
</lst>
<lst name="error">
  <str name="msg">Unknown query parser 'xport'</str>
  <int name="code">400</int>
</lst>
</response>
```

It seems for some reason that `xport` query parser isn't there.

Here's my system info:

- Solr `4.9.0`
- Java 1.8.0_66

And the config that I added to `solrconfig.xml`, as per the tutorial:

```
<requestHandler name="/export" class="solr.SearchHandler">
  <lst name="invariants">
    <str name="rq">{!xport}</str>
    <str name="wt">xsort</str>
    <str name="distrib">false</str>
  </lst>
  <arr name="components">
    <str>query</str>
  </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature came in with Solr 4.10. [SOLR-5244](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-5244). You are on Solr 4.9, so it is not there yet.